# Link error for library added with CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, cocoalumberjack

I added PaperTrailLumberjack to my project by adding the line `pod 'PaperTrailLumberjack'` to my Podfile.

I then ran the `pod install` command and got the following:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking 2.1.0 (was 2.1.0)
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.3.5)
Installing CocoaLumberjack (1.8.1)
Installing PaperTrailLumberjack (0.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

It seems to go well and I also get the correct targets in my Pods project. I can also import  `DDLog.h` and I even get macros like `DDLogVerbose` suggested by intellisense.

However, when I compile my project I get an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am hoping that I am just forgetting something silly since it's late and I am tired. But the settings for the pod targets are the same as those for the target for `AFNetworking`, and that one is working fine.

Comment: Is CocoaLumberjack in the podfile?

Comment: It isn't and it shouldn't be necessary. On their bitbucket page they say that we only need to add `pod 'PaperTrailLumberjack'`. I believe that CocoaLumberjack is linked by PaperTrailLumberjack since it does get installed. Anyway, I tried adding it and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: "DDLog" is CocoaLumberjack.

Comment: Yes. And PaperTrailLumberjack is a CocoaLumberjack logger that lets you log to papertrail (papertrailapp.com). You can see it here: https://bitbucket.org/rmonkey/papertraillumberjack.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must have gone wrong during the CocoaPods install because I have solved the problem by simply removing PaperTrailLumberjack from my podfile and running `pod install`. It said:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Removing CocoaAsyncSocket
Removing CocoaLumberjack
Removing PaperTrailLumberjack
```

I then added it again and ran `pod install` where it said:

```
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworking (2.1.0)
Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.3.5)
Installing CocoaLumberjack (1.9.0)
Installing PaperTrailLumberjack (0.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

It is now working fine.